# Workspace full error when pulling file from TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

i am using tfs with visual studio. Whenever i am trying to get the latest code i am getting an error saying my workspace is full. This goes away when i create a new workspace but again the same error repeats. Kindly help if anyone has any idea regarding this issue.

Comment: Which version of TFS and Visual Studio do you use? Could you please share the exact error messages? Capture screenshot is  better. Besides, please check your disk space, is it possible that your disk space is full?

Comment: TFS and visual studio version is 2015 and there is no issue with disk space. I dont have the screenshot with me currently.

Comment: What about other VS clients? please check if the issue also occurs on other machines. Also check if the [tf get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command) command works for you.  Besides, you can try removing all cached workspaces from the cache in the team project collection `c:\projects>tf workspaces /remove:* /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection` See [Workspaces Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/workspaces-command).